# Decimal string to character ASCII conversion - C

Tags: c, ascii

Can someone explain how to convert a string of decimal values from ASCII table to its character 'representation' in C ? For example: user input could be 097 and the function would print 'a' on the screen, but also user could type in '097100101' and the function would have to print 'ade' etc. I have written something clunky that does the opposite operation:

```
char word[30];
scanf("%s", word);

while(word[i]!=0)
{
    if(word[i]<'d')
        printf("0%d", (int)word[i]);
    if(word[i]>='d')
        printf("%d", (int)word[i]);
    i++;
}
```

but it works. Now I want to have function that works in a similar way but of course does decimal > char conversion. The point is, I cannot use any functions like 'atoi' or something like that (not sure about names, never used them ;)).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function instead of atoi:

```
char a3toc(const char *ptr)
{
    return (ptr[0]-'0')*100 + (ptr[1]-'0')*10 + (ptr[0]-'0');
}
```

So, `a3toc("102")` will return the same thing as `(char) 102`, which is an `'f'`.

If you don't see why, substitute in the values: `ptr[0]` is `'1'`, so the first part becomes `('1'-'0')*100` or `1*100` or `100`, which is what that first `1` in `102` represents.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize the input string. I'm assuming you are forcing that every letter MUST be represented in 3 characters. So break the string that way. And simply use explicit type casting to get the desired character.

I don't think I should be giving you the code for this, since it is pretty easy and seems more like a Homework question.